# Directive not loading inside ng-repeat with ng-if

Tags: angularjs, masonry

I'm creating a Masonry layout populated with images and videos and since the images-loaded directive doesn't work I'm trying to come up with a quick work around. (https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry/issues/116)

The problem I have is the link function is never fires. I'm wondering if it has something to do with ng-if's being encapsulated by an ng-repeat because according to this plunkr (http://jsfiddle.net/q05gret0/) the link function should run whenever ng-if evaluates to true

```
<div style="margin:auto;" images-loaded="false"
     masonry="{isFitWidth: true}">
    <div class="masonry-brick media-block"
         ng-repeat="mediaItem in media">
        <div ng-if="mediaItem.type === 'image/jpeg' || mediaItem.type === 'image/png'">
            <img alt="image" class="fill-width" ng-src="{{MEDIA_URL + mediaItem.urlThumbnail}}" data-loaded>
        </div>

        <div ng-if="mediaItem.type === 'video/mp4'">
            <video autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" data-loaded>
                <div trust-url url="mediaItem.url"></div>
            </video>
        </div>

        <div class="media-info container-fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-9 no-padding">
                <h5 class="media-title">{{mediaItem.name}}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 no-padding">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="deleteMedia(mediaItem)"><i
                        class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the directive in question:

```
.directive('dataLoaded', function dataLoaded() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, iElement) {
            console.log("linked!");

            iElement.bind('load', function() {
                scope.$broadcast("masonry.reload");
            });
        },
    };
})
```

Comment: The word `data` is an attribute prefixed. It's not part of the directive's name. Rename `data` to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong directive name

```
<video autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" data-loaded>
```

"data-loaded" looks for a directive with a name "loaded". So you need rename directive to "loaded" or to change the attribute to "data-data-loaded". I'd prefer to rename the directive

Comment: This is the right answer. Angualr respects JavaScript's `data-` attributes and will process any directive if it is prefixed with "data-". So `data-ng-model` works, as does `data-ng-if`.

Answer (score 2):

Please replace this line:

```
.directive('dataLoaded', function dataLoaded() {
```

with that line:

```
.directive('loaded', function dataLoaded() {
```